# Why is the curvature tensor defined to be anti-symmetric?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, curvature

I'm reading Chern's *Lectures on Differential Geometry*. On page 117 of section 4-2, he points out that
\begin{eqnarray}
d\omega_i^j - \omega_i^h \wedge\omega_h^j &=& \frac{\partial\Gamma^j_{ik}}{\partial u^l}du^l\wedge du^k - \Gamma^h_{il}\Gamma^j_{hk} du^l \wedge du^k \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial\Gamma^j_{il}}{\partial u^k} - \frac{\partial\Gamma^j_{ik}}{\partial u^l}+\Gamma^h_{il}\Gamma^j_{hk} - \Gamma^h_{ik}\Gamma^j_{hl}\right)du^k\wedge du^l.
\end{eqnarray}

Recall the expression on the left are the components of the connection matrix, which uniquely represents the connection itself.

He then defines the curvature tensor $R^j_{ikl}$ to be the expression in parentheses.

Clearly, $R^j_{ikl}$ is anti-symmetric in $k$ and $l$. For any tensor $Q^j_{ikl}$ that is *symmetric* in $k$ and $l$, we also have
$$
d\omega_i^j - \omega_i^h \wedge\omega_h^j = \frac{1}{2}\left(R^j_{ikl} + Q^j_{ikl}\right)du^k\wedge du^l.
$$

This begs the question: why is the curvature tensor defined to be $R^j_{ikl}$ and not $R^j_{ikl} + Q^j_{ikl}$ for arbitrary symmetric $Q^j_{ikl}$? If we took $R^j_{ikl} + Q^j_{ikl}$ as the definition, there would of course be curvature tensor**s**, rather than a uniquely defined curvature tensor.

Is there anything, other than convenience, that suggests defining the curvature tensor to be anti-symmetric? Does its anti-symmetry lead to great simplifications or important theorems that would otherwise be false if we were not to constrain it to be anti-symmetric?

Comment: I'm confused. What value do you get by adding on some random symmetric tensor that (as far as I can tell from what you're writing here) has nothing to do with the geometry of the manifold?

Comment: @MikeMiller What value do you get by restricting attention to an anti-symmetric curvature tensor? To someone reading through these definitions for the first time, imposing the constraint of anti-symmetry appears to come out of nowhere. As I describe in the question, it seems like there might be other ways of defining "curvature tensor" that don't necessarily require anti-symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, what Ted Shifrin wrote results in an anti-symmetry in the indices $i$ and $j$ in $R^j_{ikl}$ (for metric compatible connections), but Will Nelson asked about the other two. And this is quite easy to explain.

The reason for those to be anti-symmetric is simply that we are dealing with differential forms here. Note that for every $i$ and $j$ $\Omega^j_i = d\omega_i^j - \omega_i^h\wedge\omega_h^j$ is a differential 2-form, hence an anti-symmetric tensor with components $(\Omega^j_i)_{kl} = R^j_{ikl}$ (with respect to the tensor basis $du^k \otimes du^l$). Writing this with basis forms gives an additional factor of two and we end up with the formula
$$
\Omega^j_i = \frac 1 2  R^j_{ikl} du^k \wedge du^l.
$$
**Note that there is no ambiguity in here!** This is simply an expansion in a basis which is of course unique. I think you got confused because of the Einstein notation which is used here. Of course it looks like you can "add" a symmetric tensor in this notation, but the expansion actually stays they same.

To see the point here consider this example in two dimensions: For every anti-symmetric 2-tensor $A$ and symmetric 2-tensor $S$ we have
$$
\frac 1 2(A_{kl}+S_{kl}) du^k \wedge du^l = \frac 1 2(A_{12} + S_{12}) du^1 \wedge du^2 +  \frac 1 2(A_{21} + S_{21}) du^2 \wedge du^1 = A_{12} du^1\wedge du^2.
$$
So the component of $\frac 1 2(A_{kl}+S_{kl}) du^k \wedge du^l$ in this basis is $A_{12}$. Loosely speaking, the LHS is not a "proper" linear combination since basis forms are appearing twice.

Comment: Oops, thanks; you're right, of course. I didn't read carefully.

Comment: I agree that if you add a tensor that is symmetric in $k$ and $l$ to $R^j_{ikl}$, then the expansion for $\Omega_i^j$ remains unchanged. But that just means that although $\Omega_i^j$ is pinned down, $R^j_{ikl}$ really isn't. There is no ambiguity in $\Omega_i^j$, but there is some ambiguity in defining $R^j_{ikl}$. Right now, I think the reasons to choose the anti-symmetric version are that (a) the anti-symmetric version results in a simple formula for $R^j_{ikl}$ that's true in every coordinate system and (b) there exists no obvious, simple alternative that is not anti-symmetric.

Comment: Another approach to this question: why don't we just define the curvature tensor to be $R^j_{ikl} = 2\left(\frac{\partial \Gamma^j_{il}}{\partial u^k} - \Gamma^h_{ik} \Gamma^j_{hl}\right)$? If we did, we'd still have $\Omega^j_i = \frac{1}{2}R^j_{ikl} du^k \wedge du^l$. But I think the key here is that this formula wouldn't make $R^j_{ikl}$ a tensor! (The expression doesn't transform as a tensor. I haven't actually verified this. I'm new to this subject.) Somewhat miraculously, the anti-symmetric version *does* transform as a tensor and gives the usual expansion for $\Omega^j_i$. Make sense?

Comment: Ahhhh!!! I see the point now. I thought the defining relation of the curvature tensor was $\Omega_i^j = \frac{1}{2} R^j_{ikl} d^k \wedge d^l$, since Chern never pointed out that $\Omega_i^j = R^j_{ikl} du^k \otimes du^l$ after all. I just missed that trivial (yet key!) conclusion. If the defining relation were the first, in terms of $du^k\wedge du^l$, then the curvature tensor would be ambiguous. But with the second, it is not. To this novice, it looked as if $R^j_{ikl}$ was magically constructed and shown to transform as a tensor. But really, it's *exactly* the curvature matrix!

Comment: Yes, that is the point. Components like $R^j_{ikl}$ are always *tensor* components. But note that the anti-symmetry does not depend on the "defining relation" as you called it. The anti-symmetry is completely frame-independent property of differential forms. And since $\Omega^j_i$ is a 2-form, it is necessarily anti-symmetric in its two arguments. If you expand it in basis forms you only get $\frac 1 2 n(n-1)$ components, but because of the anti-symmetry of $\Omega^j_i$, their extension to the "full" $n^2$ tensor components is unique. There is no ambiguity!

Comment: Right. I've come to understand that the "curvature tensor" is really identical to the "curvature matrix" -- a fact that somehow was not mentioned in Chern's discussion of the subject. Previously, I had thought the curvature tensor was magically derived from the curvature matrix. I just posted another question on the subject asking if this is true for non-affine connections as well. I think it is.

Answer (score 4):

The structure group for a Riemannian structure is $O(n)$. The curvature 2-form  matrix naturally takes values in the Lie algebra of the structure group. Here $\mathfrak o(n)$ consists of all skew-symmetric matrices. I guess I should add the comment that there are plenty of connections (not compatible with the Riemannian structure in the case of the tangent bundle, or on a more general vector bundle) whose curvature is *not* skew-symmetric.

Comment: Right now, I think the skew-symmetry may be motivated by the fact that if you choose the skew-symmetric definition, the formula for $R^j_{ikl}$ in terms of $\Gamma^j_{ik}$ is true in *all* coordinate systems. Other formulas you might imagine to define the curvature might not transform so nicely, e.g., the expression $\frac{\partial\Gamma^j_{il}}{\partial u^k} - \Gamma^h_{ik}\Gamma^j_{hl}$ does not transform as a tensor (I think), whereas the anti-symmetric formula does. Does that make sense?

Comment: This actually does not answer Will's question, see my answer below.